# Code does not work with long palindromes

Tags: c, palindrome

I have an assignment I am working on where I must take a sentence input from a user, print the words in reverse order, check for anagrams, and check for palindromes. I got a function working for anagrams, and I *almost* have my palindrome function working. For now, I am only asking for two words so I can get my functions working. However, for some reason, whenever I input a lengthy palindrome (ex; racecar or detartrated compared to Mom or Dad) for both words that I ask for, the palindrome function gets messed up.

Here is the code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> //Included ctype for tolower / toupper functions
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0

//Write boolean function that will check if a word is a palindrome
bool palindrome(char a[])
{
    int c=0;
    char d[80];
    //Convert array into all lower case letters
    while (a[c])
    {
        a[c] = (tolower(a[c]));
        c++;
    }
    c = 0;

    //Read array from end to beginning, store it into another array
    while (a[c])
        c++;

    while(a[c] != 0 && c > -1)
    {
        d[c] = a[c];
        c--;
    }

    c = 0;

    while(a[c])
    {
        printf("%c", d[c]);
        printf("%c", a[c]);
        c++;
    }
    //If two arrays are equal, then they are palindromes
    for(c = 0; a[c] && d[c]; c++)
    {
        while(a[c] && d[c])
        {
        if(a[c] != d[c])
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[80], b[80];
    bool flagp;
    //Prompt user to enter sentence
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    gets(a);

    flagp = palindrome(a);

    if (flagp)
    {
        printf("\nThe word is a palindrome.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe word is not a palindrome.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs this;

```
Enter first word: racecar
_r▬a↨c e c a r
The word is not a palindrome.
```

However, if I enter 'racecar', it incorrectly states it's not a palindrome.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong :'(

Comment: 'Please tell me what I am doing wrong' - not running the code under a debugger.

Comment: I did, but it is not helping. That's why I am posting here. Why do you even bother browsing stack overflow if you are just going to tell people to use a debugger?

Comment: Here's one thing you may want to check out. Your algorithm doesn't account for the line ending character (/n on most systems) or the null terminator at the end of all C strings.

Comment: @RivalDog - debugging skills are ESSENTIAL for any software developer.  If you cannot debug this code yourself, you cannot develop software and you should choose another profession.  I'm sorry, but it IS that simple :(  It is indeed hard work, but you have to do it.

Comment: @MartinJames Don't be sorry then. If it is a fact of life, it is a fact of life and that's that. =)

I've only just started programming. I don't have a thorough background in the profession yet, but I'm getting better. Would you not agree that stackoverflow is useful for beginners?

Comment: @SevenBits Doesn't checking if the value is zero account for those? If it does not, should I add this line in;

    || a[c] != '\n' || a[c] != //null terminator, don't know code for that

Comment: A zero `char` value is not the same as a null terminator, which is `'\0'`. So checking would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. So `a[c] != d[c]` is true when you expect it to be false.
2. You've demonstrated with your `printf` that this is because `d[c]` is garbage.
3. That means that `d` doesn't contain the reverse of `a`.
4. So this leads one to inspect the following snippet:

   ```
   while(a[c] != 0 && c > -1)
   {
       d[c] = a[c];
       c--;
   }
   ```

   It's attempting to create a reversed copy, but it's quite clearly failing at reversing anything seeing as it's putting at the same index as it's taking.

(You did the first three steps. Why did you stop there?)

Honestly, there's no reason for `d` to exists at all. It can all be done in-place.

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | r | a | c | e | c | a | r |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     ^                       ^
     |   compare these two   |


         ^               ^
         |  then these   |


                ...
```

So the code would look like:

```
size_t len = strlen(a);
if (len) {
   size_t i = 0;
   size_t j = len - 1;
   while (i < j) {
      if (a[i++] != a[j--])
         return 0;
   }
}

return 1;
```

---

Notes:

1. Please don't do `#define true 1` and `#define false 0`. These differ from C's definition, so you could get the wrong result if you do `if (b == true)` instead of `if (b)`.
2. `c` usually denotes a `char`. `i` (and `j` and `k`) are more commonly used for indexes.

Comment: "It's attempting to create a reversed copy, but it's quite clearly failing at reversing anything seeing as it's putting at the same index as it's taking."

By gods, you're right. Herp derp.

"(You did the first three steps. Why did you stop there?)"

What steps are you talking about? o.O

"Please don't do #define true 1 and #define false 0. These differ from C's definition, so you could get the wrong result if you do if (b == true) instead of if (b)."

Are the definitions for True and False in the stdio.h? As of right now, that's the only header I really use.

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: The ones numbered 1 to 4. // Any non-zero number is true. That can't be represented by a symbol.

Comment: @RivalDog; C99 provides definition for the `true` and `false` in `stdbool.h` header. But you have to define it if you are in C89 mode.

Comment: @ikegami; I disagree with your first point of **note**. `if (b == true)` is same as `if (b)`.

Comment: @haccks, You can disagree all you want, but you should try it with `b=2;`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `palindrome` function. In the snippet

```
while(a[c] != 0 && c > -1)
{
    d[c] = a[c];
    c--;
}
```

you are not reversing `a`.

And snippet

```
while (a[c])
    c++;
```

cause `c` to go out of bound by `1`.

I fixed these issues. Your modified code:

```
bool palindrome(char a[])
{
    int c=0;
    char d[80];
    //Convert array into all lower case letters
    while (a[c])
    {
        a[c] = (tolower(a[c]));
        c++;
    }
    c = 0;

    //Read array from end to beginning, store it into another array
    while (a[c])
        c++; 
        c=c-1; // Number of elements in a is one less than that of counter c.

    int i = 0;  // taking another counter for array d
    while(a[c] != 0 && c > -1)
    {
        d[i] = a[c];
        i++;
        c--;
    }
    d[i] = '\n'; // last element of array mut be a nul char
    c = 0;

    while(a[c])
    {
        printf(" %c\t", d[c]);
        printf(" %c\n", a[c]);
        c++;
    }
    //If two arrays are equal, then they are palindromes
    for(c = 0; a[c] && d[c]; c++)
    {

         if(a[c]  != d[c] )
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

After all, this function is not good enough for checking palindrome. Example:

Input:

```
I am a     I
```

you will get

```
The word is not a palindrome.
```

Comment: Thanks for the work you put into modifying the code! But you are right, my logic was incorrect. ikegami's works great. I added his suggestion into my code and now the palindrome function works great!